# How do I register a dependency in Autofac within the scope of an outer component while retaining Dispose support?

Tags: autofac, dispose

I have non-disposable class `ReadModelRepository` that depends on (but does not own) an instance of the disposable class `ReadModelDbContext`. Within a `Module`, I want to configure my Autofac 3.0.2 container so that `ReadModelDbContext` is resolved (one instance per dependency) only when `ReadModelRepository` objects are created.

This is what I currently have:

```
builder.RegisterType<ReadModelRepository>().As<IReadModelRepository>();
builder.Register(c => new ReadModelDbContext(_connectionStringName)).AsSelf();
```

However, I do not want any arbitrary class to be able to resolve `ReadModelDbContext` using the registration provided by the module. Indeed, it's probable that other classes will need to resolve different `ReadModelDbContext` instances.

To solve this, I could use `WithParameter`, as in this snippet:

```
builder
    .RegisterType<ReadModelRepository> ().As<IReadModelRepository> ()
    .WithParameter (
        (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof (ReadModelDbContext), 
        (p, c) => new ReadModelDbContext (_connectionStringName));
```

However, I also need Autofac to automatically dispose the `ReadModelDbContext` when the lifetime scope resolving the `ReadModelRepository` (or actually that of its resolving component) ends. Using `WithParameter`, this doesn't seem to work.

So, in essence, I'd like to register a dependency only in the context of an outer component, with `Dispose` being called when the lifetime scope of the outermost component ends. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I've actually adopted a different approach: I register the inner component (`ReadModelDbContext`) with a private key:

```
var privateKey = new object();
builder.Register(c => new ReadModelDbContext(_connectionStringName)).Keyed<ReadModelDbContext>(privateKey);
builder.Register(ctx => new ReadModelRepository(ctx.ResolveKeyed<ReadModelDbContext>(privateKey))).As<IReadModelRepository>();
```

Since nobody else has the key, this effectively makes the `ReadModelDbContext` registration private to the `ReadModelRepository`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this will help you.

```
public class RepositoryManager : IDisposable
{
    private ILifetimeScope m_RootLifetimeScope;
    private ILifetimeScope m_RepositoryScope;
    private bool m_Disposed;

    public RepositoryManager(ILifetimeScope rootLifetimeScope)
    {
        m_RootLifetimeScope = rootLifetimeScope;
    }

    public IReadModelRepository CreateReadModelRepository()
    {
        m_RepositoryScope = m_RootLifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope(
                builder =>
                    {
                        builder.RegisterType<ReadModelRepository>().As<IReadModelRepository>();
                        builder.Register(c => new ReadModelDbContext(_connectionStringName)).AsSelf();
                    });
        return m_RepositoryScope.Resolve<IReadModelRepository>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (m_Disposed) return;

        m_RepositoryScope.Dispose(); //ReadModelDbContext will be disposed

        m_Disposed = true;
    }
}

//registration
builder.RegisterType<RepositoryManager>().InstancePerDependency();

//using
using (var repositoryManager = yourContainer.Resolve<RepositoryManager>())
{
    IReadModelRepository repository = repositoryManager.CreateReadModelRepository();
}
```

Comment: I guess I can even make the `RepositoryManager` transparent, so that clients don't need to call it explicitly:
`builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<RepositoryManager>().CreateReadModelRepository()).As<IReadModelRepository>();`

Comment: It's not perfect, but it's the best answer given here that solves my problem, so I'll make it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having `ReadModelRepository` take a dependency on `Func<Owned<ReadModelDBContext>>`.

Something like:

```
using Autofac.Features.OwnedInstances;

class ReadModelRepository : IReadModelRepository
{
    public ReadModelRepository(Func<Owned<ReadModelDBContext>> contextFactory)
    {
        _ctxFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public DoSomethingUseful()
    {
        using (var context = _ctxFactory())
        {
            // use context.Value in here;
            // it will be disposed when exiting the block
            ...
        }
    }

    private readonly Func<Owned<ReadModelDBContext>> _ctxFactory;
}
```

Then you can register ReadModelRepository and ReadModelDBContext however you wish.

This approach doesn't solve the problem of preventing other classes from resolving a `ReadModelDBContext`, but you maybe you could play visibility games by making all these types *internal* to the assembly except for `IReadModelRepository`.  If you can't get to the type, you certainly can't ask for an instance from the container.

[The Autofac Wiki has some documentation on this approach.](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OwnedInstances)